# Long-running operations in web-application

Tags: rest, http, web, cloud

Web application operations are generally meant to be quick to avoid long wait times to users.  However, some operations the web application may perform may be computationally-intensive and take a fair bit of time.  What is the best practice in REST to deal with such operations that may be take several minutes yet require an immediate response to users?  Is it okay for the web application to take several minutes to return the response of the HTTP request, or is it better to return a 202 response, process in the background somewhere else, and then provide some form of notification to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it okay for the web application to take several minutes to return the response of the HTTP request

No.  Part of the problem with this approach is that if the server doesn't acknowledge the request in a timely fashion, the client won't know that it reached its intended destination.

> is it better to return a 202 response, process in the background somewhere else, and then provide some form of notification to the user?

Yes.  That's exactly what 202 Accepted is designed for

> The 202 response is intentionally noncommittal.  Its purpose is to allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until the process is completed.  The representation sent with this response ought to describe the request's current status and point to (or embed) a status monitor that can provide the user with an estimate of when the request will be fulfilled.

It can help, I think, to remember that we're talking about your integration domain; the client isn't talking to your app.  It's instead talking to your API, which pretends to be a web site that the client can integrate with.  So your client sends the request to the API, and the API responds with an accepted message accompanied by a bunch of links that will help the client continue with the protocol and eventually reach its goal.